# How to fill html form with php scritp, which get array?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I have a html page:

```
   <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-12">
                <h2 class="tm-question-header">Question 1</h2>
                <p style="color: black" id="q1">Who is the best?</p>
                <div class="tm-q-choice-container">
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                            <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="q1" type="radio" value="q1_a1" />
                            <span id="q1a1" style="color: black">Ivo</span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                            <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="q1" type="radio" value="q1_a2" />
                            <span id="q1a2" style="color: black">Pavel</span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                            <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="q1" type="radio" value="q1_a3" />
                            <span id="q1a3" style="color: black">Dominik</span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                            <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="q1" type="radio" value="q1_a4" />
                            <span id="q1a4" style="color: black">Vendula</span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <br>
            </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-12 text-center tm-submit-container">
                <button type="submit" href="#" class="btn btn-primary tm-btn-submit">Submit</button>
            </div>
    </form>
```

And now I need to add qestions to html with php script. And the script get array like this:

```
   $questions = array(
    "1q" => array(
        "q1" => "Who is the best?",
        "q1a1" => "Ivo",
        "q1a2" => "Pavel",
        "q1a3" => "Dominik",
        "q1a4" => "Vendula",
    ),
    "2q" => array(
        "q2" => "Who is the best?",
        "q2a1" => "Ivo",
        "q2a2" => "Pavel",
        "q2a3" => "Dominik",
        "q2a4" => "Vendula",
    )
);
```

How I can do it? Some tips or solves? I need to have prepare all forms items? If yes, how I remove empty questions? Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need a loop with a counter.

```
<div class="col-12">
    <?php
        $count = 1;
        foreach($questions as $question) {
            $q = 'q' . $count; //q1, q2, q3 etc
            ?>
                <h2 class="tm-question-header">Question <?= $count ?></h2>
                <p style="color: black" id="<?= $q ?>"><?= $question[$q] ?></p>
                <div class="tm-q-choice-container">
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                        <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="<?= $q ?>" type="radio" value="<?= $q ?>_a1" />
                        <span id="<?= $q ?>a1" style="color: black"><?= $question[$q.'a1'] ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                        <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="<?= $q ?>" type="radio" value="<?= $q ?>_a2" />
                        <span id="<?= $q ?>a2" style="color: black"><?= $question[$q.'a2'] ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                        <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="<?= $q ?>" type="radio" value="<?= $q ?>_a3" />
                        <span id="<?= $q ?>a3" style="color: black"><?= $question[$q.'a3'] ?></span>
                    </label>
                    <br>
                    <label class="tm-q-choice">
                        <input class="tm-radio-group-1 with-gap" name="<?= $q ?>" type="radio" value="<?= $q ?>_a4" />
                        <span id="<?= $q ?>a4" style="color: black"><?= $question[$q.'a4'] ?></span>
                    </label>
                </div>
                <hr>
                <br>
            <?
            $count++;
        }
    ?>
</div>
```

On each loop, I create a variable called `$q`, which contains something like `q1`, `q2` (depending on the `$count` variable, which starts at 1 and goes up by 1 on every loop) etc, and I use that variable in several places to pull the data from the array for each question.

This should fill in your entire form with every question in your array.